# Add class to current category menu item

Tags: menus

I'm trying to figure out how to add an "active" class to a menu link when in that category.

For example, if in the Shirts Category, I would like it to have an active class so I can style it differently: 
**Shirts** | Jeans | Shoes

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
function show_parent_categories( $args = array() ) {

$args = array(  
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'show_option_none' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'parent' => $category->term_id,
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

$count = count($product_categories);
 if ( $count > 0 ){
 echo "<div id='main-categories-wrapper'><ul id='main-categories'>";
 foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
   echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</li>';

 }
 echo "</ul></div>";
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `is_category()` You can check the documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/)

```
function show_parent_categories( $args = array() ) {

$args = array(  
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'show_option_none' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'parent' => $category->term_id,
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

$count = count($product_categories);
 if ( $count > 0 ){
 echo "<div id='main-categories-wrapper'><ul id='main-categories'>";
 foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
   echo '<li><a class="'.(is_category($product_category->slug)?'active':'').'" href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</li>';

 }
 echo "</ul></div>";
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting some sort of syntax error though from that line. Do you know what might be causing it?

Comment: When I run it through a php validator it says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' in your code"

Comment: I have made the changes, i have added an extra bracket, let me know if the answer works for you. If it works please mark my answer. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't give an error, but it also doesn't produce a class either. Someone else suggested adding 'is_tax( 'product_cat', $product_category->slug )' which does add a class. 

However I'm wondering if it's possible to have the active class stay on the category link when you're in a subcategory of that category as well.